# What happens when the lock limit is reached?

Tags: postgresql, locking, isolation-level

My question is about the default isolation level: "read committed".
As I understand, during a read committed transaction, when we update a record, the system puts a lock on that record, so other transactions would wait.
Is this correct?

Other: and there's a limit in the config file for the maximum number of locks in a transaction: `max_locks_per_transaction`.

What happens when that limit is reached? I made a test and nothing happened. Does the system exchange the row-level locks for a full-table lock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`max_locks_per_transaction` does not apply to rows, but to *objects*.
The fact that rows do not count is made explicit in the documentation:

From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-locks.html

> This parameter controls the average number of object locks allocated
>   for each transaction; individual transactions can lock more objects as
>   long as the locks of all transactions fit in the lock table. **This is
>   not the number of rows that can be locked**; that value is unlimited.

The information necessary to row locking is written in the row itself.

Comment: Thank you. So to reach this limit, I would have to for example create 65 tables and lock them in one transaction?

Comment: @CrouchingKitten: if your transaction is the only one running on the instance, the limit is documented to be `max_locks_per_transaction * (max_connections + max_prepared_transactions)`, so it's much more than `max_locks_per_transaction` in a default configuration.

Comment: When running DDL in tx I see one lock per created table, one per pk, one per index, a few per foreign key and a few for toast. Adding columns seems to be free. So you might reach the default 6400 lock entries if you create 1000 non-trivial tables or drop/create 500. having said that, if you reach the global limit (shared with all transactions) you get a „out of shared memory“ (which is quite missleading) and a transaction rollback. There is no lock escalation in this area, and the max_locks_per_transaction is only a sizing estimate not a per transaction limit (unlike the name suggests).